# Is it possible to debug qml in vscode?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I mean is it possible to debug in vscode? I only found the link https://forum.qt.io/topic/107303/debugging-in-vscode is related to the question. But the link hasn't clear answer, anyone could be help? very thx for you!

Comment: Check this link https://www.kdab.com/using-visual-studio-code-for-qt-apps-pt-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Visual Studio code for Qt development by adding extensions. Install the **QML Syntax/Tools** extension to get language support for QML and develop Qt Quick apps using QML Hot Reload: [How to Use Visual Studio Code for Qt and QML Development](https://blog.felgo.com/develop-qt-quick-apps-with-visual-studio-code-qml-extension#how-to-vs-code-qt-qml)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've found the extention [QML Debug extension (orcun-gokbulut.qml-debug)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orcun-gokbulut.qml-debug).

You can try it your own. I'm running it with some issues now, and I want to solve them with the extension developer. Unfortunatelly breakpoints are working only on Linux (not yet running on Windows).